# PutExtra then GetStringExtra Still Pointing To Null?

Tags: android, android-intent

newbie to Androdi Studio here, I've encountered a problem which is usually very easy to solve, but it's hard this time, I don't know what I'm missing.

I'm getting my Key here by throwing it in as an extra: (I'm using firebase as my DB)

```
DatabaseReference mChildDatabase = mDatabaseRef.child("Users").push();
            String key_user = mChildDatabase.getKey();
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
            in.putExtra("USER_KEY" ,  key_user);
            in.putExtra("USER_EMAIL" ,  String.valueOf(dataUser.child("emailUser").getValue()));
            in.putExtra("USER_PASS" ,  String.valueOf(dataUser.child("passWordUser").getValue()));
            in.putExtra("USER_ID" ,  String.valueOf(dataUser.child("userID").getValue()));
            startActivity(in);
```

And on the second activity, I get the extra here:

```
  String userNameString = name.getText().toString();
        String userPhoneString  = phone.getText().toString();
        String userAgeString  = age.getText().toString();
        String userBirthString = birth.getText().toString();
        String userUserNameString = username.getText().toString();

        //GET USER KEY  FROM INTENT
        String userKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_KEY");
        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userKey).child("userName").setValue(userNameString);
        String userEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_EMAIL");
        String userPass = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_PASS");
        String userID = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID");
```

Notice this line? `mFirebaseDatabase.child(userKey).child("userName").setValue(userNameString);`

I'm getting the error on that line because it says that I'm pointing to a null, I don't know whats happening I've been up to it for hours. So i decided to finally ask it here, I may be just dumb or what. but yeah I'm misssing something.

I declared the Reference like this:

```
  DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef,mFirebaseDatabase;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference().child("Users");
```

And my firebase looks like this:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drGjx.png)

I don't know whats happening why I can't set my `userName` to something.  And why it's pointing to null? I have reused some of my past codes, but neither was working. I had an app that uses firebase too and it implements just like what I did, but on this case I just can't set it right. Please help.

UPDATE: The logcat shows that the key is the one not being shown, that's why its pointing to null, however I'm still stuck. I'm pulling my hairs out god I'm so dumb. Still not working

Comment: Just check the log for userKey and userNameString. A check is it coming null?

Comment: userKey is the one coming null @PrafullaMalviya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [retrieving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) use below code:

```
    DatabaseReference dataUser = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Users");
    dataUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                //dataSnapshot points to the User node with list of users
                //Retrieve data from the childrens emailUser,passWordUser,userID and Invoke start activity
                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("onDataChange:", "PARENT: " + childDataSnapshot.getKey());
                    Log.i("emailUser: ",
                            String.valueOf(childDataSnapshot.child("emailUser").getValue()));
                    Log.i("passWordUser: ",
                            String.valueOf(childDataSnapshot.child("passWordUser").getValue()));
                    Log.i("userID: ",
                            String.valueOf(childDataSnapshot.child("userID").getValue()));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent` can be used for **reading Data Once**.

Comment: would it still get the key that's being used? I used this on the MainActivity, getKey(), thats why I'm passing it by intent. To make sure the key is the same.

Comment: Sir, the problem is that without the key I couldn't even get the value, that I was going for, this is why I am putting it as an extra. So that I could make use of the key on the Profile class and use that data to that what you are suggesting. Let's say atabaseReference dataUser= mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Users"). But as you can see I need the key in order to get the child of the User that I want.

Comment: It's a deadend without the key that I got from my MainActivity

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sir @Rissmon, what if I want to read the part, let's say under the `Users - Anne`    I got the `userName` by using `String userName = String.valueOf(childDataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue());`    but what if I want to use that string in order to target something that matches it under `User`, but it's not a key. I tried doing, this.

` myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userName);` then used myRef in a listener, but I got NULL, lol what should I do in this case?

Comment: In your case, the child "userName" reside inside a key. So you need to access child by using the key.
For Ex:
 myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(key).child(userName)

Comment: Take a look at this pic sir, since it will be hard to post something in the comments. http://prntscr.com/ijk3cn  and here is my database http://prntscr.com/ijk50x what I want to fetch as userName is for example that `kobadolo` how do I make that possible? I can understand your last comment and have tried it but it also failed and resulted to null. Actually at the same tiem the key was created a separate input was built and the parent of their info is  the name.

Comment: your answer earlier made the first one happen, but for the other its returning null unfortunately.

Comment: This is what appears on the log on the userName: `DataSnapshot{ key = userName, value = null}`

Comment: getting the key_user seemed to be fine

Comment: The problem is the userName I guess

Comment: Ahhhh it's working, I remade it to this:                         `String userName =  String.valueOf(childDataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue());`

Answer (score 0):

Please, Have a look

```
if(userKey!=null && userNameString!=null){
 if(mFirebaseDatabase.child(userKey)!=null){
   if(mFirebaseDatabase.child(userKey).child("userName")!=null){
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(userKey).child("userName").setValue(userNameString);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: tried this sir, but did not work :( thanks for answering though

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `String userKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_KEY");`, try this code:

```
String userKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity."USER_KEY");
```

Also, include some logging or toasts to see the actual values of the variables.

Comment: this seems to be a syntax error... i tried adding .class to it, how should it be formatted?